# Why is 'love' used in the present continuous form here?

Tags: word-usage, present-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

[image]

I am reading a book called 'High School grammar' by P.C Wren and H.Martin. We know 'love' falls in the category of stative verbs, but they have used the word 'love' in the present continuous/present perfect continuous. Is there something wrong with the book or my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Close the book and find something newer.  Wren and Martin is a textbook intended to educate the children of the British Raj in India, and contains much that is out of date, or confusing. For example the description of the perfect tense is simply wrong in expressions like

> I've played tennis since I was young.

This has nothing to do with a "finished, complete or perfect at the time of speaking".

You are correct that "loving" is rare in the present continuous form.  It can be used to indicate that the feeling of "love" has suddenly and recently begun, but is expected to end soon.

> I'm loving this steak.  It's tender and juicy.

It tends to be limited to casual expressions.

A better, newer book would probably choose a different verb  (the use of "love" is likely because in Latin Grammars,  *amo* (I love) is near the start of most verb lists, so is used in many examples of Latin Grammar.)

The solution is simple.  Dump this book.